# Trouble logging out user in Django

Tags: python, django

I've got a function in my Django project to log out a user when a link is clicked. The problem is that when I click the link to logout, I get a 404 with the message saying "No User matches the given query". I can't seem to figure out what's going on here, I double checked the documentation and it looks like I'm doing everything right.

So far, I've found that the only way to log out is by going into the Django Admin and clicking the logout link at the top. I'm not sure why it's acting the way it is, but anyways, below is my code.

login function:

```
def user_login(request):
    loginform = LoginForm()
    new_user = NewUser()
    # Initialize variables with empty string
    invalid = ''
    disabled = ''
    # Make sure that the form was POSTed
    if request.method == 'POST':
        loginform = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if loginform.is_valid():
            # Grab the submitted values
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            # Attempt to grab a User object with submitted credentials
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            # If a User object was returned and the User is active,
            # log in the user and redirect the User to their profile page
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:detail', args=(user.username,)))
                # If the User is not active, display an error message and send them to the
                # login page
                else:
                    disabled = 'User is not active'
                    context = {'loginform': loginform, 'invalid': invalid, 'disabled': disabled}
                    return render(request, 'users/login.html', context)
            # If no User object was returned, display an error message and send them to the
            # login page
            else:
                messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'The username or password you entered is incorrect. Please try again.')
                context = {'loginform': loginform, 'disabled': disabled, 'new_user': new_user}
                return render(request, 'users/login.html', context)
        # If the form is not valid, display an error message and send them to the
        # login page
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "In order to login, you must complete the form.")
            context = {'loginform': loginform, 'disabled': disabled, 'new_user': new_user}
            return render(request, 'users/login.html', context)
    # If the form was not POSTed, refresh the LoginForm and send them to the
    # login page
    else:
        loginform = LoginForm()
        context = {'loginform': loginform, 'invalid': invalid, 'disabled': disabled, 'new_user': new_user}
        return render(request, 'users/login.html', context)
```

logout function:

```
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:index'))
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^signup/$', views.new_user, name='new_user'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='u_login'),
    url(r'^browse/$', views.browse, name='browse'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/account/$', views.account, name='account'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.user_logout, name='u_logout'),
)
```

link to be clicked in order to logout:

```
<li><p><a href="{% url 'users:u_logout' %}" class="t-w-t">Logout</a></p></li>
```

I've made sure that the required settings in order to use the Django authentication system are in place. Thanks in advance for the help and please let me know if I need to post more code.

**** EDIT ****

I've figured out a way to make this work, although I feel like it's very dirty and not the best way to do this. I've changed my urls.py to:

```
url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/logout/$', views.user_logout, name='u_logout'),
```

and the view function to:

```
def user_logout(request, username):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:index'))
```

Now, in the template I'm also passing the username to the view and it works properly. Again, I feel like this is very dirty for some reason, but it works. If anyone has a better solution, that would be great.

Comment: Is the link rendering properly to "logout/" (maybe the namespace in urls.py is not well defined?)

Comment: The link is rendering properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with your logout function itself. It is simply a function of your URL configuration. The pattern for your "detail" function is just `r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$'`, which will *also* match the string "logout". So, when a user clicks on a link to logout, Django will route it to the "detail" view, which will attempt to find a user named "logout" and fail with the error you see.

You can easily fix this by moving your "logout" pattern above the "detail" one in urls.py, since URLs are matched in order.